# Getting Error loading templates, please run 'flixel download'.?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeflixel, lime-haxe

i am getting, `Error loading templates, please run 'flixel download'.` after a fresh install on a windows pc.

Everything is freshly installed.

I tried :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

i am confused what to do next ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get when you run `haxelib path flixel-templates` gives the relevant clue:

> Error: Library lime version 2.9.1 is not installed

Flixel depends on older versions of OpenFL and Lime - Lime 2.9.1 to be exact, hence the error. You can solve this by running the following two commands (answer the "install it?" prompt with yes):

```
haxelib set lime 2.9.1
haxelib set openfl 3.6.1
```

Note that if you run `haxelib install flixel`, it should automatically install the correct versions of Lime and OpenFL. Perhaps you used a different setup?

---

**Update:** I've just released flixel-templates 2.4.5 and flixel-demos 2.4.3, which should avoid this issue altogether in the future.